# Hello I would like to identify a plane seen at Evergreen museum

Tags: united-states

This is a picture of a plane I'm curious to identify, seen this summer at [Evergreen aviation & Space museum](https://www.evergreenmuseum.org/). Unfortunately it was past opening hours, so I didn't manage to find someone with more information on the site.

Cheers

[image: unknown plane]

Comment: Vtc as I'm struggling to see this as a history question.

Comment: We have users who are amazing at this kind of thing, but it would still be good form to help them out with as much info as you can provide so they don't waste their time. For example, I linked the museum in question (I think). Assuming you have this original photo stored electronically somewhere, would it be possible to show a zoomed crop for any identifying marks? If I squint, it looks like I see something of that sort back towards the tail.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for [Aviation StackExchange.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Aviation.SE.

Comment: Bastard's taking up four parking spaces!

Answer (score 7):

I suppose it's a **[Northrop F-89 Scorpion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_F-89_Scorpion)** (but i can't tell the exact model). There's a complete [Gallery of F-89's on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/F-89_Scorpion_Photo_Gallery?uselang=en), showing the different types.

[image: Eric Salard (53-2674 NORTHROP F-89J SCORPION) [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons" href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3A53-2674_NORTHROP_F-89J_SCORPION_(12159947845).jpg]

<sup>Source: [Eric Salard](http://www.flickr.com/people/16103393@N05), 53-2674 NORTHROP F-89J SCORPION, [CC BY-SA 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3A53-2674_NORTHROP_F-89J_SCORPION_(12159947845).jpg)</sup>

Comment: Definitely the same fuselage. It even has the same 5 notches (vents?) on the underside of the first panel section behind the nose.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's definitely the bird I was looking for. Air intakes and wheel size are specific. I appreciate you spend time to log the answer even though my question was off-topic. Thanks again!